Table function in SQL Server with multiple parameters as an argument
I have a table in SQL Server 2016 named df:
-- Create a new table with department and gender columns
CREATE TABLE df 
(
    country VARCHAR(50),
    year INT,
    val1 INT,
    val2 INT,
    val3 INT,
    department VARCHAR(50),
    gender VARCHAR(10)
);

-- Insert data into the new table, including department and gender
INSERT INTO df (country, year, val1, val2, val3, department, gender) 
VALUES ('USA', 2020, 4, 4, 5, 'Sales', 'Male'),
('USA', 2020, 4, 4, 5, 'Sales', 'Male'),
('USA', 2020, 5, 5, 5, 'Sales', 'Female'),
('USA', 2020, 5, 5, 5, 'Sales', 'Female'),
('USA', 2020, 1, 1, 5, 'Sales', 'Male'),
('USA', 2020, 3, 3, 5, 'Sales', 'Female'),
('USA', 2020, 4, 2, 5, 'Sales', 'Male'),
('USA', 2020, 1, 1, 5, 'Sales', 'Female'),
('USA', 2020, 2, 2, 5, 'Sales', 'Male'),
('Canada', 2020, 2, 2, 3, 'HR', 'Female'),
('Canada', 2020, 2, 2, 3, 'HR', 'Female'),
('Canada', 2020, 2, 2, 3, 'HR', 'Male'),
('Canada', 2020, 2, 2, 3, 'HR', 'Male'),
('Canada', 2020, 5, 5, 3, 'HR', 'Female'),
('Canada', 2020, 5, 5, 3, 'HR', 'Male'),
('Canada', 2020, 1, 1, 3, 'HR', 'Female'),
('Canada', 2020, 1, 1, 3, 'HR', 'Male'),
('Canada', 2020, 3, 4, 3, 'HR', 'Female'),
('Canada', 2020, 3, 4, 3, 'HR', 'Male'),
('Canada', 2020, 5, 4, 3, 'HR', 'Female'),
('Canada', 2020, 5, 4, 5, 'HR', 'Male'),
('Canada', 2020, 5, 4, 5, 'HR', 'Female'),
('Germany', 2022, 5, 5, 4, 'IT', 'Male'),
('France', 2020, 1, 1, 2, 'Finance', 'Female'),
('France', 2020, 1, 1, 2, 'Finance', 'Female'),
('France', 2020, 3, 2, 2, 'Finance', 'Male'),
('France', 2020, 3, 4, 2, 'Finance', 'Female'),
('France', 2020, 3, 5, 5, 'Finance', 'Male'),
('France', 2020, 3, 4, 4, 'Finance', 'Female'),
('France', 2020, 3, 4, 4, 'Finance', 'Male'),
('France', 2020, 3, 4, 3, 'Finance', 'Female'),
('UK', 2021, 4, 2, 3, 'Marketing', 'Male'),
('Australia', 2022, 3, 3, 4, 'Support', 'Female'),
('Italy', 2020, 5, 5, 5, 'Operations', 'Male'),
('Italy', 2020, 5, 5, 5, 'Operations', 'Female'),
('Italy', 2020, 5, 1, 1, 'Operations', 'Male'),
('Italy', 2020, 4, 4, 1, 'Operations', 'Female'),
('Italy', 2020, 2, 1, 2, 'Operations', 'Male'),
('Italy', 2020, 3, 5, 3, 'Operations', 'Female'),
('Spain', 2021, 1, 2, 3, 'Customer Service', 'Male'),
('Mexico', 2022, 4, 4, 4, 'Logistics', 'Female'),
('Brazil', 2020, 4, 1, 1, 'R&D', 'Male'),
('Brazil', 2020, 4, 1, 1, 'R&D', 'Female'),
('Brazil', 2020, 4, 3, 4, 'R&D', 'Male'),
('Brazil', 2020, 5, 3, 5, 'R&D', 'Female'),
('Brazil', 2020, 5, 3, 5, 'R&D', 'Male'),
('Brazil', 2020, 3, 3, 1, 'R&D', 'Female'),
('Brazil', 2020, 2, 3, 1, 'R&D', 'Male');

-- Select all rows from the new table to check the data
SELECT * FROM df;

With this table, I create some percentages and a count column based on some filtering.
-- Parameters
DECLARE @Year INT = 2020;
DECLARE @Metric VARCHAR(50) = 'count'; 
DECLARE @Gender VARCHAR(20) = NULL; -- Set to specific gender (e.g., 'Male', 'Female') or NULL to include all
DECLARE @Department VARCHAR(50) = NULL; -- Set to specific department (e.g., 'HR', 'Engineering') or NULL to include all
-- Set @Metric to 'dissatisfaction', 'satisfaction', or 'count'

WITH UnpivotedData AS 
(
    SELECT country, gender, department, year, Vals
    FROM 
        (SELECT country, gender, department, year, val1, val2, val3
         FROM df) AS SourceTable
    UNPIVOT 
        (Vals FOR ValueColumn IN (val1, val2, val3)) AS Unpivoted
    WHERE year = @Year
),
Proportions AS 
(
    SELECT 
        country,
        gender,
        department,
        CASE 
            WHEN Vals = 1 THEN 'Very Dissatisfied'
            WHEN Vals = 2 THEN 'Dissatisfied'
            WHEN Vals = 3 THEN 'Neutral'
            WHEN Vals = 4 THEN 'Satisfied'
            WHEN Vals = 5 THEN 'Very Satisfied'
        END AS SatisfactionLevel,
        COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY country, gender, department) AS Proportion
    FROM 
        UnpivotedData
    GROUP BY 
        country, gender, department, Vals
),
Pivoted AS 
(
    SELECT country, gender, department, 
           [Very Dissatisfied], 
           [Dissatisfied], 
           [Neutral], 
           [Satisfied], 
           [Very Satisfied]
    FROM Proportions
    PIVOT 
        (MAX(Proportion)
         FOR SatisfactionLevel IN ([Very Dissatisfied], [Dissatisfied], [Neutral], [Satisfied], [Very Satisfied])) AS p
),
CountryCounts AS 
(
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN country IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE country END AS country,
        gender, 
        department,
        COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM df
    WHERE year = @Year
    -- Apply filters for gender and department if provided
    AND (@Gender IS NULL OR gender = @Gender)
    AND (@Department IS NULL OR department = @Department)
    GROUP BY CASE WHEN country IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE country END, gender, department
),
OrderedData AS 
(
    SELECT 
        p.country,
        p.gender,
        p.department,
        [Very Dissatisfied],
        [Dissatisfied],
        [Neutral],
        [Satisfied],
        [Very Satisfied],
        c.Total,
        CASE 
            WHEN @Metric = 'satisfaction' THEN ISNULL([Satisfied], 0) + ISNULL([Very Satisfied], 0)
            WHEN @Metric = 'dissatisfaction' THEN ISNULL([Very Dissatisfied], 0) + ISNULL([Dissatisfied], 0)
            WHEN @Metric = 'count' THEN c.Total
        END AS SortValue
    FROM Pivoted AS p
    INNER JOIN CountryCounts AS c ON p.country = c.country AND p.gender = c.gender AND p.department = c.department
)
SELECT 
    country,
    gender,
    department,
    [Very Dissatisfied],
    [Dissatisfied],
    [Neutral],
    [Satisfied],
    [Very Satisfied],
    Total
FROM 
    OrderedData
ORDER BY 
    SortValue DESC;

I want to create a table function that will have 3 arguments:

Metric
Year
Factor

Factor can be the Gender or the Department or both of them. If for example the Factor is the Gender the table to be grouped by the Gender and if is the Department to be grouped by Department.
If both to be grouped by both. If the Factor is null or default to not be grouped at all.
Regarding the Year: if the Year is passed in to be grouped by year. If the Year is null, show all the years without grouping.
Is there a way to do that in SQL Server?
I have a fiddle here

I'm curious why you appear to have completely ignored my recommendations from your previous question on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/79273109/14868997 your query is much more complicated than it needs to be in the first place. What does "Factor can be the Gender or the Department or both of them.If for example the Factor is the Gender the table to be grouped by the Gender and if is the Department to be grouped by Department.If both to be grouped by both.If the Factor is null or default to not be grouped at all" can you show examples because it's not clear.

@Charlieface if the i will give the Factor  argument the value Gender the resulted table must have 7 columns: 1) Gender ,2-6 the very dissatified to very satified and the count. if the Factor is the Department to have again 7 columns :1) Department  ,2-6 the very dissatified to very satified and the count. If the Factor is both Gender and Department the resulted table must  have 8 columns :1) Gender 2) Department ,3-7 the very dissatified to very satified and 8 the count.

So you want the columns to be dynamic? (Impossible in a function) Or do you want nulls for the extra columns? How would you group in each case? It's really not clear, please give examples.

@Charlieface null for the extra columns

Where is your attempt? The documentation for creating functions is very good, should be straight forward to follow and have a go yourself.

And you really need to be providing a [mre] with emphasis on minimal i.e. not production code, but the simplest code which illustrates the issue you are facing. And of course sample data and desired results.

Please read : Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, even for a very simple SQL query?

Aside: You can use a simple case, rather than a searched case: case Vals when 1 then 'Very Dissatisfied' when 2 then 'Dissatisfied' ... end. You may also want to consider adding an else clause to handle any unexpected values.

As I told you on your previous SQL question, you are hugely over-complicating this.
You can do the filtering, unpivot and pivot in a single level of CTE, and you only need one level to add the Total, which itself wouldn't be necessary if there was an ID column, because then you could do COUNT(DISTINCT ID).
To create a function, just add the normal CREATE FUNCTION syntax. You can't add ORDER BY to a table function, it's basically just a view. You need to add that on to the outer query.
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.MyAggregation (
    @Year INT,
    @Gender VARCHAR(20), -- Set to specific gender (e.g., 'Male', 'Female') or NULL to include all
    @Department VARCHAR(50), -- Set to specific department (e.g., 'HR', 'Engineering') or NULL to include all
    @Metric VARCHAR(50) -- Set @Metric to 'dissatisfaction', 'satisfaction', or 'count'
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

WITH AllRows AS (
      SELECT *,
          COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY country, gender, department, year) AS Total
      FROM df
      WHERE (year = @Year OR @Year IS NULL)
        AND (Department = @Department OR @DepARTMENT IS NULL)
        AND (Gender = @Gender OR @Gender IS NULL)
)
SELECT
      country,
      gender,
      department,
      year,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Vals = 1 THEN 1 END) * 1.0
         / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY country, gender, department, year) AS [Very Dissatisfied],
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Vals = 2 THEN 1 END) * 1.0
         / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY country, gender, department, year) AS [Dissatisfied],
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Vals = 3 THEN 1 END) * 1.0
         / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY country, gender, department, year) AS [Neutral],
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Vals = 4 THEN 1 END) * 1.0
         / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY country, gender, department, year) AS [Satisfied],
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Vals = 5 THEN 1 END) * 1.0
         / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY country, gender, department, year) AS [Very Satisfied],
      MIN(Total) AS Total,
      CASE @Metric
        WHEN 'satisfaction' THEN
          COUNT(CASE WHEN Vals IN (4, 5) THEN 1 END) * 1.0
            / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY country, gender, department, year)
        WHEN 'dissatisfaction' THEN
          COUNT(CASE WHEN Vals IN (1, 2) THEN 1 END) * 1.0
           / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY country, gender, department, year)
        WHEN 'count' THEN MIN(Total)
      END AS SortValue
FROM AllRows
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        ('val1', val1),
        ('val2', val2),
        ('val3', val3)
) v(ValueColumn, Vals)
GROUP BY
    country,
    gender,
    department,
    year;

Then you just do
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyAggregation(2020, NULL, NULL, 'count')
ORDER BY
    SortValue;    

db<>fiddle
Note that the sort-value parameter should not be passed in from a variable or lateral join, as that will slow down your query a lot. If it's a constant string then the optimizer can factor it out.
Adding in dynamic grouping substantially complicates this, because now you need to null out the values before you group them up (as shown in the other answer). It will also be really slow on large tables, as you can't use indexes. I would strongly recommend you create separate functions with different grouping/partitioning constructs, alternatively do this in dynamic SQL.

We are applying value substitution for the column to be grouped by. For example, if parameter @factorGender is null, we group by value gender else group by constant value all - in fact, no grouping by gender.
To simplify things, subquery is your UNPIVOT-PIVOT operation equivalent. We can directly count values dispersion for val1,val2,val3. Expression
iif(val1=1,1.0,0)+iif(val2=1,1.0,0)+iif(val3=1,1.0,0) cv1

or as
case  when val1=1 then 1.0 else 0 end
   +case when val2=1 then 1.0 else 0 end
   +case when val3=1 then 1.0 else 0 end as cv1

counts val1=1,val2=1,val3=1 for all rows.
See example
Update1. After @DaleK comment, I decided that I really needed to answer the question more precisely and suggest an example of a function and an example of its use.

CREATE FUNCTION SatisfiedByGroups (
 -- -- Parameters for row filters
    @Year INT = 2020
   ,@Metric VARCHAR(50) ='dissatisfaction' -- Set @Metric to 'satisfaction','dissatisfaction', 'count' ; 
   ,@Gender VARCHAR(20) = NULL  -- Set to specific gender (e.g., 'Male', 'Female') or NULL to include all
   ,@Department VARCHAR(50) = NULL  -- Set to specific department (e.g., 'HR', 'Engineering') or NULL to include all

-- parameters for grouping
   ,@factorYear int = null -- 0 ; -- Set to any value if do not group by, else null
   ,@factorgender VARCHAR(50) = null  --'all'  -- Set to any value if do not group by, else null
   ,@factorDepartment VARCHAR(50) = null --'all'  -- Set to value if do not group by, else null
   ,@factorCountry VARCHAR(50) = null -- 'all' -- Set to value if do not group by, else null
  )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
select grCountry country,grGender gender,grDepartment department
  ,sum(cv1)/count(*)/3.0 [Very Dissatisfied]
  ,sum(cv2)/count(*)/3.0 [Dissatisfied]
  ,sum(cv3)/count(*)/3.0 [Neutral]
  ,sum(cv4)/count(*)/3.0 [Satisfied]
  ,sum(cv5)/count(*)/3.0 [Very Satisfied]
  ,count(*) total
  ,CASE 
      WHEN @Metric = 'satisfaction' THEN (sum(cv4)+sum(cv5))/3.0/count(*)
      WHEN @Metric = 'dissatisfaction' THEN (sum(cv1)+sum(cv2))/3.0/count(*)
      WHEN @Metric = 'count' THEN count(*)
   END AS SortValue
  ,grCountry,grYear,grDepartment,grGender,@metric as metric
from(
select coalesce(country,'unknown') country,year ,gender,department
  ,iif(val1=1,1.0,0)+iif(val2=1,1.0,0)+iif(val3=1,1.0,0) cv1 
  ,iif(val1=2,1.0,0)+iif(val2=2,1.0,0)+iif(val3=2,1.0,0) cv2
  ,iif(val1=3,1.0,0)+iif(val2=3,1.0,0)+iif(val3=3,1.0,0) cv3
  ,iif(val1=4,1.0,0)+iif(val2=4,1.0,0)+iif(val3=4,1.0,0) cv4
  ,iif(val1=5,1.0,0)+iif(val2=5,1.0,0)+iif(val3=5,1.0,0) cv5
  ,coalesce(@factorYear,year) grYear
  ,coalesce(@FactorDepartment,department)grDepartment
  ,coalesce(@factorGender,gender) grGender
  ,coalesce(@factorCountry,coalesce(country,'UNKNOWN')) grCountry
from df
WHERE (year = @Year or @Year is null)
      -- Apply filters for gender and department if provided
    AND (@Gender IS NULL OR gender = @Gender)
    AND (@Department IS NULL OR department = @Department)
)d 
group by grCountry,grYear,grDepartment,grGender
);

And call this function
select * from SatisfiedByGroups(
        2020 -- @year
       ,'count' -- @metric
       ,NULL    -- @gender
       ,NULL    -- @department
       ,null -- @factorYear
       ,null -- @factorgender
       ,null -- @factorDepartment
       ,null -- @factorCountry
)

Output is



country
gender
department
Very Dissatisfied
Dissatisfied
Neutral
Satisfied
Very Satisfied
total
SortValue
grCountry
grYear
grDepartment
grGender
metric




Canada
Female
HR
0.095238
0.190476
0.333333
0.142857
0.238095
7
7.000000
Canada
2020
HR
Female
count


Canada
Male
HR
0.111111
0.222222
0.333333
0.111111
0.222222
6
6.000000
Canada
2020
HR
Male
count


France
Female
Finance
0.266666
0.200000
0.266666
0.266666
0.000000
5
5.000000
France
2020
Finance
Female
count


USA
Male
Sales
0.133333
0.200000
0.000000
0.333333
0.333333
5
5.000000
USA
2020
Sales
Male
count


USA
Female
Sales
0.166666
0.000000
0.166666
0.000000
0.666666
4
4.000000
USA
2020
Sales
Female
count


Brazil
Male
R&D
0.250000
0.083333
0.250000
0.250000
0.166666
4
4.000000
Brazil
2020
R&D
Male
count


Brazil
Female
R&D
0.333333
0.000000
0.333333
0.111111
0.222222
3
3.000000
Brazil
2020
R&D
Female
count


France
Male
Finance
0.000000
0.222222
0.333333
0.222222
0.222222
3
3.000000
France
2020
Finance
Male
count


Italy
Female
Operations
0.111111
0.000000
0.222222
0.222222
0.444444
3
3.000000
Italy
2020
Operations
Female
count


Italy
Male
Operations
0.333333
0.222222
0.000000
0.000000
0.444444
3
3.000000
Italy
2020
Operations
Male
count



So try run query with another group condition.
select * from SatisfiedByGroups(
        2020 -- @year
       ,'dissatisfaction' -- @metric
       ,NULL    -- @gender
       ,NULL    -- @department
       ,null  -- @factorYear
       ,'all' -- @factorgender
       ,'all' -- @factorDepartment
       ,null -- @factorCountry
)




country
gender
department
Very Dissatisfied
Dissatisfied
Neutral
Satisfied
Very Satisfied
total
SortValue
grCountry
grYear
grDepartment
grGender
metric




France
all
all
0.166666
0.208333
0.291666
0.250000
0.083333
8
0.375000
France
2020
all
all
dissatisfaction


Italy
all
all
0.222222
0.111111
0.111111
0.111111
0.444444
6
0.333333
Italy
2020
all
all
dissatisfaction


Brazil
all
all
0.285714
0.047619
0.285714
0.190476
0.190476
7
0.333333
Brazil
2020
all
all
dissatisfaction


Canada
all
all
0.102564
0.205128
0.333333
0.128205
0.230769
13
0.307692
Canada
2020
all
all
dissatisfaction


USA
all
all
0.148148
0.111111
0.074074
0.185185
0.481481
9
0.259259
USA
2020
all
all
dissatisfaction



fiddle
If on your server do not available function IIF(...)
convert this expression by using case when ... end
  ,case  when val1=1 then 1.0 else 0 end
   +case when val2=1 then 1.0 else 0 end
   +case when val3=1 then 1.0 else 0 end as cv1
  ,case  when val1=2 then 1.0 else 0 end
   +case when val2=2 then 1.0 else 0 end
   +case when val3=2 then 1.0 else 0 end as cv2
  ,case  when val1=3 then 1.0 else 0 end
   +case when val2=3 then 1.0 else 0 end
   +case when val3=3 then 1.0 else 0 end as cv3
  ,case  when val1=4 then 1.0 else 0 end
   +case when val2=4 then 1.0 else 0 end
   +case when val3=4 then 1.0 else 0 end as cv4
  ,case  when val1=5 then 1.0 else 0 end
   +case when val2=5 then 1.0 else 0 end
   +case when val3=5 then 1.0 else 0 end as cv5
--   ,iif(val1=1,1.0,0)+iif(val2=1,1.0,0)+iif(val3=1,1.0,0) cv1 
--   ,iif(val1=2,1.0,0)+iif(val2=2,1.0,0)+iif(val3=2,1.0,0) cv2
--  ,iif(val1=3,1.0,0)+iif(val2=3,1.0,0)+iif(val3=3,1.0,0) cv3
--  ,iif(val1=4,1.0,0)+iif(val2=4,1.0,0)+iif(val3=4,1.0,0) cv4
--  ,iif(val1=5,1.0,0)+iif(val2=5,1.0,0)+iif(val3=5,1.0,0) cv5

fiddle
and

@DaleK, thank you for comment. I don't see any particular need to turn a fairly simple query into a function. However, since the OP has asked for such a question, I will think about how to do it for a while. Unless  convert variable declarations into function parameters, and frame the query itself with a function.

iif does not work in sql real world setup.

@HomerJaySimpson - why not? What error do you get?

@DaleK is before 2012 version

@HomerJaySimpson the first line of your question says you are using 2016...

That said its trivial to convert IIF to CASE (the documentation states that thats essentially all it is).

I think, IIF(...) is available on 2016. I can convert it to a case when, but it's not so important for the question.

2012 actually... but OP needs to correctly tag their SQL Server version.

Op says "I have a table in SQL Server 2016". May be specific compatibility level ?

Yeah maybe, odd that they were quick to tell you it wasn't working, but slow to confirm what actual version they are using. You could throw a short example at the end of your answer showing how to convert IIF to CASE to cover all bases (up to you).
